# MySQL UPDATE Performance ...which is faster

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Supposed I have the following 2 MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    IndexNumber INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FieldOne TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FieldTwo VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
    FieldThree DATE,
    FieldFour INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (IndexNumber, FieldThree),
    UNIQUE KEY (FieldOne, FieldTwo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    IndexNumber INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FieldFive TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FieldSix TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IndexNumber) REFERENCES Table1 (IndexNumber),
    KEY (IndexNumber),
    KEY (FieldFive, FieldSix)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, I want to do a couple of queries to retrieve some matching records, and after each SELECT query I want to update the matched records so that they won't be retrieved again until tomorrow.

The SELECT queries are as follows:

```
SELECT table1.fieldone, 
       table1.fieldtwo 
FROM   table2 
       INNER JOIN table1 
               ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber 
WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1 
       AND table2.fieldsix = 2; 

SELECT table1.fieldone, 
       table1.fieldtwo 
FROM   table2 
       INNER JOIN table1 
               ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber 
WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1 
       AND table2.fieldsix = 3 
       AND table1.fieldthree <> Curdate();
```

My question is this - what is the quickest way to update the matched records after each select query so that the next SELECT query doesn't match it?

I could either retrieve the "IndexNumber" field in the SELECT query then I could do an UPDATE query as follows, passing in the "IndexNumber" field values:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    fieldthree = Curdate(), 
       fieldfour = (fieldfour + 1) 
WHERE  indexnumber IN (...indexnumbers...)ve = 1 
AND    table2.fieldsix = 3 
AND    table1.fieldthree <> curdate();
```

or I could repeat the WHERE from the SELECT query and hope that caching makes it faster:

```
UPDATE table2 
       INNER JOIN table1 
               ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber 
SET    table1.fieldthree = Curdate(), 
       table1.fieldfour = ( table1.fieldfour + 1 ) 
WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1 
       AND table2.fieldsix = 2; 

UPDATE table2 
       INNER JOIN table1 
               ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber 
SET    table1.fieldthree = Curdate(), 
       table1.fieldfour = ( table1.fieldfour + 1 ) 
WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1 
       AND table2.fieldsix = 3 
       AND table1.fieldthree <> Curdate() 
       AND table1.fieldthree <> Curdate();
```

Note that the UPDATE query will be executed immediately after the SELECT query and before the next SELECT query is executed.

Which of these two approaches is more efficient?

Comment: TLDR. Why don't you test both approach instead of asking us?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com.

Comment: Now I read and isnt clear if the update happen bettwen Query1 and Query2 or after Query2. Also isnt clear what you want to do because there isnt any data or expected result.

Comment: Fastest is often a theoretical until you test it on *your* hardware with *your* system configuration. What works for someone on a 128GB highly tuned MySQL server with 64-cores may perform brutally on a more modest system.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I was hoping someone might have an insight but I'll come back and post an update once I have run some tests ...

Answer (score 0):

First, when you have `id .. AUTO_INCREMENT` in an InnoDB table, there is no difference between `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and `PRIMARY KEY(id, other_col)` .

Second, your `table2` has no explicit `PRIMARY KEY`; this is 'bad'.  A hidden PK will be provided for you, but it won't be as 'good' as explicitly having your own.

For this select:

```
    INNER JOIN  table1  ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber
    WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1
      AND  table2.fieldsix = 2;
```

It will start with `table2` because there is filtering (`WHERE`).  The optimal indexes are

```
table2:  INDEX(fieldfive, fieldsix,   -- in either order
               indexnumber)           -- to make the index "covering"
table1:   (indexnumber)               -- it's already the PK, so good
```

For this select:

```
    INNER JOIN  table1  ON table2.indexnumber = table1.indexnumber
    WHERE  table2.fieldfive = 1
      AND  table2.fieldsix = 3
      AND  table1.fieldthree <> Curdate();  -- not easy to optimize
```

Again, it will start with table2, and the same indexes as above are optimal.  Another note...  Since there is at most 1 row in `table1` for the given `indexnumber` (when `JOINing`), all the `<>` will do is filter out some rows.  There is *no* need to adjust any index.

(Your first `UPDATE` is invalid since it mentions `fieldsix` without mentining `table2`.)

The second `UPDATE` is pretty much covered by discussing the `SELECT`.

The third `UPDATE` may hit fewer rows due to the date test, but that means it is *not* the same as the second `UPDATE` -- because it won't always increment `fieldfour`.